# Why my if else statement showing result for all condition?

Tags: android-studio, if-statement, sharedpreferences, rules

I don't know how to solve this. I've ruled out conditions to advice possibility disease based on symptom choose, but unfortunately, it showing all result. I've already set the result condition by false by default.

```
if ((radioMale || radioFemaleMonopause || radioFemaleNotMonopause) &&
                        (radioYes && duration2 && !NoneOther1) &&
                        (condition1 || condition2 || condition3 || condition4) ||
                        (leftArm || bothArms || leftShoulder || bothShoulder || throatOrNeck || jaw || dizziness || shortnessOfBreath || stress || nausea || pulse || sweating || BP || notActive || diabetic || smoke || familyHistory || hadHeartAttackBefore || backNeck || fatigue || sleepDisturbance || NoneHead || overweight || NoneOther))
                { angina = true;


                    }
                if ((radioMale || radioFemaleMonopause || radioFemaleNotMonopause) &&
                        (radioNo && duration2 && !NoneOther1) &&
                        (condition1 || condition2 || condition3 || condition4) ||
                        (leftArm || bothArms || leftShoulder || bothShoulder || throatOrNeck || jaw || dizziness || shortnessOfBreath || stress || nausea || pulse || sweating || BP || notActive || diabetic || smoke || familyHistory || hadHeartAttackBefore || backNeck || fatigue || sleepDisturbance || NoneHead || overweight || NoneOther))
                { highRiskMaleNo = true;


                }

                if ((radioMale || radioFemaleMonopause || radioFemaleNotMonopause) &&
                        (radioYes && !NoneOther1) &&
                        (duration3 || duration4) &&
                        (condition1 || condition2 || condition3 || condition4) ||
                        (leftArm || bothArms || leftShoulder || bothShoulder || throatOrNeck || jaw || dizziness || shortnessOfBreath || stress || nausea || pulse || sweating || BP || notActive || diabetic || smoke || familyHistory || hadHeartAttackBefore || backNeck || fatigue || sleepDisturbance || NoneHead || overweight || NoneOther))
                { highRiskMaleYes = true;//unstable angina

                }
                if ((radioMale || radioFemaleMonopause || radioFemaleNotMonopause) &&
                        (radioNo && !NoneOther1) &&
                        (duration3 || duration4) &&
                        (condition1 || condition2 || condition3 || condition4) ||
                        (leftArm || bothArms || leftShoulder || bothShoulder || throatOrNeck || jaw || dizziness || shortnessOfBreath || stress || nausea || pulse || sweating || BP || notActive || diabetic || smoke || familyHistory || hadHeartAttackBefore || backNeck || fatigue || sleepDisturbance || NoneHead || overweight || NoneOther))
                { highRiskMaleNo = true;

                }

                if ((radioMale || radioFemaleMonopause || radioFemaleNotMonopause) &&
                        (radioYes && duration1 && !NoneOther1) &&
                        (condition1 || condition2 || condition3 || condition4) ||
                        (leftArm || bothArms || leftShoulder || bothShoulder || throatOrNeck || jaw || dizziness || shortnessOfBreath || stress || nausea || pulse || sweating || BP || notActive || diabetic || smoke || familyHistory || hadHeartAttackBefore || backNeck || fatigue || sleepDisturbance || NoneHead || overweight || NoneOther))
                { unlikely = true;

                }
                if ((radioMale || radioFemaleMonopause || radioFemaleNotMonopause) &&
                        (radioNo && duration1 && !NoneOther1) &&
                        (condition1 || condition2 || condition3 || condition4) ||
                        (leftArm || bothArms || leftShoulder || bothShoulder || throatOrNeck || jaw || dizziness || shortnessOfBreath || stress || nausea || pulse || sweating || BP || notActive || diabetic || smoke || familyHistory || hadHeartAttackBefore || backNeck || fatigue || sleepDisturbance || NoneHead || overweight || NoneOther))
                { unlikely = true;


                }

                if ((radioMale || radioFemaleMonopause || radioFemaleNotMonopause) &&
                        (radioYes && !NoneOther1) &&
                        (duration1 || duration2 || duration3 || duration4) &&
                        (condition5 || condition6 || condition7 || condition8) ||
                        (leftArm || bothArms || leftShoulder || bothShoulder || throatOrNeck || jaw || dizziness || shortnessOfBreath || stress || nausea || pulse || sweating || BP || notActive || diabetic || smoke || familyHistory || hadHeartAttackBefore || backNeck || fatigue || sleepDisturbance || NoneHead || overweight || NoneOther))
                { unlikely = true;

                }
                if ((radioMale || radioFemaleMonopause || radioFemaleNotMonopause) &&
                        (radioNo && !NoneOther1) &&
                        (duration1 || duration2 || duration3 || duration4) &&
                        (condition5 || condition6 || condition7 || condition8) ||
                        (leftArm || bothArms || leftShoulder || bothShoulder || throatOrNeck || jaw || dizziness || shortnessOfBreath || stress || nausea || pulse || sweating || BP || notActive || diabetic || smoke || familyHistory || hadHeartAttackBefore || backNeck || fatigue || sleepDisturbance || NoneHead || overweight || NoneOther))
                { unlikely = true;

                }

                if ((radioMale || radioFemaleMonopause || radioFemaleNotMonopause) &&
                        (radioYes && NoneOther1) &&
                        (duration1 || duration2 || duration3 || duration4) ||
                        (leftArm || bothArms || leftShoulder || bothShoulder || throatOrNeck || jaw || dizziness || shortnessOfBreath || stress || nausea || pulse || sweating || BP || notActive || diabetic || smoke || familyHistory || hadHeartAttackBefore || backNeck || fatigue || sleepDisturbance || NoneHead || overweight || NoneOther))
                { indeterminate = true;

                }
                if ((radioMale || radioFemaleMonopause || radioFemaleNotMonopause) &&
                        (radioNo && NoneOther1) &&
                        (duration1 || duration2 || duration3 || duration4) &&
                        (condition5 || condition6 || condition7 || condition8) ||
                        (leftArm || bothArms || leftShoulder || bothShoulder || throatOrNeck || jaw || dizziness || shortnessOfBreath || stress || nausea || pulse || sweating || BP || notActive || diabetic || smoke || familyHistory || hadHeartAttackBefore || backNeck || fatigue || sleepDisturbance || NoneHead || overweight || NoneOther))
                { indeterminate = true;


                }
```

This is my default boolean

```
            angina = false;
            unstableAngina = false;

            highRiskMaleNo = false;
            highRiskMonopauseNo = false;

            unlikely = false;
            indeterminate = false;
```

My friend told to add all other false value after the true value for all condition, it works, it only showing one result, but for all condition tick, the result showing is indeterminate only. For example

```
if ((radioMale || radioFemaleMonopause || radioFemaleNotMonopause) &&
                    (radioYes && duration2 && !NoneOther1) &&
                    (condition1 || condition2 || condition3 || condition4) ||
                    (leftArm || bothArms || leftShoulder || bothShoulder || throatOrNeck || jaw || dizziness || shortnessOfBreath || stress || nausea || pulse || sweating || BP || notActive || diabetic || smoke || familyHistory || hadHeartAttackBefore || backNeck || fatigue || sleepDisturbance || NoneHead || overweight || NoneOther))
            { angina = true;
                highRiskMaleNo = false;
                highRiskMonopauseYes = false;//unstable angina
                unlikely = false;
                indeterminate = false;

                }
            if ((radioMale || radioFemaleMonopause || radioFemaleNotMonopause) &&
                    (radioNo && duration2 && !NoneOther1) &&
                    (condition1 || condition2 || condition3 || condition4) ||
                    (leftArm || bothArms || leftShoulder || bothShoulder || throatOrNeck || jaw || dizziness || shortnessOfBreath || stress || nausea || pulse || sweating || BP || notActive || diabetic || smoke || familyHistory || hadHeartAttackBefore || backNeck || fatigue || sleepDisturbance || NoneHead || overweight || NoneOther))
            { highRiskMaleNo = true;
                angina = false;
                highRiskMaleYes = false;  //unstable angina
                //highRiskMaleNo = false;
                unlikely = false;
                indeterminate = false;

            }

            if ((radioMale || radioFemaleMonopause || radioFemaleNotMonopause) &&
                    (radioYes && !NoneOther1) &&
                    (duration3 || duration4) &&
                    (condition1 || condition2 || condition3 || condition4) ||
                    (leftArm || bothArms || leftShoulder || bothShoulder || throatOrNeck || jaw || dizziness || shortnessOfBreath || stress || nausea || pulse || sweating || BP || notActive || diabetic || smoke || familyHistory || hadHeartAttackBefore || backNeck || fatigue || sleepDisturbance || NoneHead || overweight || NoneOther))
            { highRiskMaleYes = true;//unstable angina
                angina = false;
                //highRiskMaleYes = false;  //unstable angina
                highRiskMaleNo = false;
                unlikely = false;
                indeterminate = false;
            }
            if ((radioMale || radioFemaleMonopause || radioFemaleNotMonopause) &&
                    (radioNo && !NoneOther1) &&
                    (duration3 || duration4) &&
                    (condition1 || condition2 || condition3 || condition4) ||
                    (leftArm || bothArms || leftShoulder || bothShoulder || throatOrNeck || jaw || dizziness || shortnessOfBreath || stress || nausea || pulse || sweating || BP || notActive || diabetic || smoke || familyHistory || hadHeartAttackBefore || backNeck || fatigue || sleepDisturbance || NoneHead || overweight || NoneOther))
            { highRiskMaleNo = true;
                angina = false;
                highRiskMaleYes = false;  //unstable angina
                //highRiskMaleNo = false;
                indeterminate = false;
                unlikely = false;
            }

            if ((radioMale || radioFemaleMonopause || radioFemaleNotMonopause) &&
                    (radioYes && duration1 && !NoneOther1) &&
                    (condition1 || condition2 || condition3 || condition4) ||
                    (leftArm || bothArms || leftShoulder || bothShoulder || throatOrNeck || jaw || dizziness || shortnessOfBreath || stress || nausea || pulse || sweating || BP || notActive || diabetic || smoke || familyHistory || hadHeartAttackBefore || backNeck || fatigue || sleepDisturbance || NoneHead || overweight || NoneOther))
            { unlikely = true;
                highRiskMaleNo = false;
                highRiskMonopauseYes = false;//unstable angina
                //unlikely = false;
                indeterminate = false;
            }
            if ((radioMale || radioFemaleMonopause || radioFemaleNotMonopause) &&
                    (radioNo && duration1 && !NoneOther1) &&
                    (condition1 || condition2 || condition3 || condition4) ||
                    (leftArm || bothArms || leftShoulder || bothShoulder || throatOrNeck || jaw || dizziness || shortnessOfBreath || stress || nausea || pulse || sweating || BP || notActive || diabetic || smoke || familyHistory || hadHeartAttackBefore || backNeck || fatigue || sleepDisturbance || NoneHead || overweight || NoneOther))
            { unlikely = true;
                angina = false;
                highRiskMaleYes = false;  //unstable angina
                highRiskMaleNo = false;
                //unlikely = false;
                indeterminate = false;

            }

            if ((radioMale || radioFemaleMonopause || radioFemaleNotMonopause) &&
                    (radioYes && !NoneOther1) &&
                    (duration1 || duration2 || duration3 || duration4) &&
                    (condition5 || condition6 || condition7 || condition8) ||
                    (leftArm || bothArms || leftShoulder || bothShoulder || throatOrNeck || jaw || dizziness || shortnessOfBreath || stress || nausea || pulse || sweating || BP || notActive || diabetic || smoke || familyHistory || hadHeartAttackBefore || backNeck || fatigue || sleepDisturbance || NoneHead || overweight || NoneOther))
            { unlikely = true;
                highRiskMaleNo = false;
                highRiskMonopauseYes = false;//unstable angina
                //unlikely = false;
                indeterminate = false;
            }
            if ((radioMale || radioFemaleMonopause || radioFemaleNotMonopause) &&
                    (radioNo && !NoneOther1) &&
                    (duration1 || duration2 || duration3 || duration4) &&
                    (condition5 || condition6 || condition7 || condition8) ||
                    (leftArm || bothArms || leftShoulder || bothShoulder || throatOrNeck || jaw || dizziness || shortnessOfBreath || stress || nausea || pulse || sweating || BP || notActive || diabetic || smoke || familyHistory || hadHeartAttackBefore || backNeck || fatigue || sleepDisturbance || NoneHead || overweight || NoneOther))
            { unlikely = true;
                angina = false;
                highRiskMaleYes = false;  //unstable angina
                highRiskMaleNo = false;
                //unlikely = false;
                indeterminate = false;
            }

            if ((radioMale || radioFemaleMonopause || radioFemaleNotMonopause) &&
                    (radioYes && NoneOther1) &&
                    (duration1 || duration2 || duration3 || duration4) ||
                    (leftArm || bothArms || leftShoulder || bothShoulder || throatOrNeck || jaw || dizziness || shortnessOfBreath || stress || nausea || pulse || sweating || BP || notActive || diabetic || smoke || familyHistory || hadHeartAttackBefore || backNeck || fatigue || sleepDisturbance || NoneHead || overweight || NoneOther))
            { indeterminate = true;
                highRiskMaleNo = false;
                highRiskMonopauseYes = false;//unstable angina
                unlikely = false;
               //indeterminate = false;
            }
            if ((radioMale || radioFemaleMonopause || radioFemaleNotMonopause) &&
                    (radioNo && NoneOther1) &&
                    (duration1 || duration2 || duration3 || duration4) &&
                    (condition5 || condition6 || condition7 || condition8) ||
                    (leftArm || bothArms || leftShoulder || bothShoulder || throatOrNeck || jaw || dizziness || shortnessOfBreath || stress || nausea || pulse || sweating || BP || notActive || diabetic || smoke || familyHistory || hadHeartAttackBefore || backNeck || fatigue || sleepDisturbance || NoneHead || overweight || NoneOther))
            { indeterminate = true;
                angina = false;
                highRiskMaleYes = false;  //unstable angina
                highRiskMaleNo = false;
                unlikely = false;
                //indeterminate = false;
            }
```

Comment: Maybe you should check the `else` statement.

Comment: can you please write the example,

Comment: What example? I don't know what you want. I'm talking about `if () {  } else if () {  } else {  }`.

Comment: @forpas, already tried if else also before this, but it only read the if condition and ignore the else if statement

Comment: It will ignore the else part only if the condition in the if statement is true.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.